# How to utilize a printer (Zebra TLP 2844) in a Ruby on Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, zebra-printers

I need use a printer (a **Zebra TLP 2844**) in my Ruby on Rails project.

Ideally, I need a way to have a local machine send a file, **.EPL**, or string to the printer for consumption.

How might I do this?

Comment: Please include a brief description of the software architecture/network  topology so someone can better address your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser does not have direct access to a printer.

I would solve as follows:

Create a `desktop` application, which would be installed on the client computer.

This app would make queries in a print queue (`database`, `rest api`). And print the labels.

Comment: While this will give you more control, Zebra now has a Browser Print SDK which eliminates the need to develop a desktop application.

Answer (score 3):

My team had to deal with this a few years ago. The best solution we came up with writing the ZPL by hand.

As for sending it to the printer, you can just write the ZPL to a socket.

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/masonjm/74e15e15d161f29698a3) of two classes: one builds the ZPL manually, the other sends the data to the printer.

Comment: The printer haven't network acess, only serial and USB.